# Advice on which non .Net technology to use for file transfer over the internet

Tags: licensing, communication

My newest task is going to be to implement automatic update of a licence:

The program detects that the licence is expired or about to expire and offers the user to automatically upate this. So far so good. Now what is needed:

- The program sends the user's credentials to a win 2008 server over the internet.
- The server checks the credentials and if they are OK generates a licence file that is sent back.

How to implement these steps if I cannot use .Net technology?

Comment: @ Oded: I use a VB application. I can use WCF, but that creates a dependency on .Net. I am interested in alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What not instead of transferring a file, think of it like invoking a web service (or web page) on the server and that returning the content of the license file?

In the VB application you then receive the page response and save that to a local file.

This alternative is used in [LicenseSpot](http://www.licensespot.com) for online activation. You can check the API documentation for a general idea.

Comment: Thanks, I am such a noob in this area that I have no idea how to create the webservice and how to invoke it remotely. I found pocketSoap for the invoking, but how to create the webservice to have it talk to?